# Manifold with all principal curvatures zero.

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

Why if a connected manifold has all its prinvipal curvatures zero, then it must be an hyperplane?

Comment: You mean a connected hypersurface in $\Bbb R^{n+1}$? It must be contained in a hyperplane, yes.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**: If all principal curvatures are $0$, show that the normal vector must be constant on the hypersurface.